# Similar Functions to pause()?

Tags: c, linux

Are there any other similar functions to pause() in Linux?

ex: to use in this code

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){  

int delay = 5;  
alarm(delay);  
pause();  
return0;  
}
```

Comment: It would help if you'd describe what `pause()` does. If it's a Windows-specific function, many of the people who can tell you about Linux may not be familiar with it. You have a typo: `return0` should be `return 0`. You're also missing one or two `#include` directives. Please copy-and-paste a compilable working program.

Comment: I found sleep() also working...anyway thanks for your contribution

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve your problem -- but adding the information I suggested would make this question more useful to future readers.

Comment: sure I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

How about `getchar`?

```
puts("Press Enter to continue...");
getchar();
```

The user does have to press Enter (as opposed to any key), but this is platform agnostic.

Comment: Various tricks such as changing the terminal out of line-buffered mode can rectify that, albeit with some platform dependence - and the need to remember to set it back.